# Check if a div has an ID that contains a string plus a variable

Tags: jquery

I feel there will be a very amateur mistake I'm making with this, but after an entire day of pulling what hair I have left out, here goes:

I need to be able to check if a div exists on the page that contains as it's ID a string + a variable which is being generated when the mouse hovers over another div.

**For example:**

I have a DIV on my sidebar navigation that contains the words 'Google' in a span.

When the user hovers over this div, I create a variable that contains the text from the span, let's call this variable sideBarButtonName.

I then would like to search the DOM for any divs whose ID contains the word "nav_" + sideBarButtonName and if such a div exists, throw an alert.wb
If this doesn't exist, there is an else statement I have that is working just fine.

I cannot get this right! Help!

The part I'm struggling with is the count that checks if the

```
 $("div[id*='nav_']") + (sideBarButtonName).length > 0
```

I've created a fiddle that replicates the issue I'm having.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pu5FJ/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `sideBarButtonName` inside of the selector. As your ID is an exact match, you can target it directly:

```
$('#nav_' + sideBarButtonName).length
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pu5FJ/4/)

Answer (score 1):

From your fiddle it seems that "contains" really means *equals*, so:

```
if ($('#nav_' + sideBarButtonName).length) {
    // alert here
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pu5FJ/5/)

However, seeing your HTML structure, you may wish to improve it a little:

```
<div class="sideBarButton" data-url="http://www.google.com">
    <div id="nav_Google" class="side-nav">
    </div>
    <span>Google</span>
</div>
```

Then you check whether an element with "side-nav" class exists inside:

```
$('.sideBarButton').mouseenter(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.side-nav').length) {
        // alert here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("div[id='nav_" + sideBarButtonName + "']").length > 0) {
```

or

```
$("div #nav_" + sideBarButtonName + "").length > 0)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pu5FJ/3/)

Comment: @Anshu check the answer buddy its different no need to use *

Comment: No need to downvote a correct answer, both answered 8mins ago.